# How to go to next page in modal

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have this modal when I click on a card it pop up here is the pic attached

[image: when I click on next and previous I want to go to next and previous page respectively]

here is the code with the following code I am seeting the data which is showing on modal when it open on click

```
         export const setDirectorsDetail = (blog) => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
 

    const docRef = firestore.collection('boardOfDirectors').doc(blog?.id);
    firestore.collection(`boardOfDirectors/${blog.id}/boardOfDirectorDetails`).where('directorId', '==', docRef).get().then(snapshots => {
        snapshots.docs.forEach(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                let combineData = { ...blog, ...doc.data(), ...{ key: doc.id } }
                dispatch({
                    type: SET_DETAILS_DIRECTIOR,
                    payload: combineData
                })



            } else {
                console.log("combune data error:");
            }
        });
    }).catch((error) => console.log("error :", error));


}
}
```

here is the code for toggle next I want to go to the next page when I call this action

```
    export const toggleNext = () => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    
}

}
```

plz tell me how should I procceed next thank you